# Entity Framework Bug: Exception with PredicateBuilder and comparing nulls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, predicatebuilder

I was able to get my method (below) to run in LinqPad, but when switching to my actual code (using Entity Framework), I get this error:

> "Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types."

The error occurs if I uncomment either of the two commented lines here (the actual error doesn't occur until the last line in the method is run):

```
public List<LotEquipmentScan> GetLotEquipmentScans(string maximoAssetNumber, decimal? manufacturerId, decimal? partNumber)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<LotEquipmentScanRecord>();

    // Note: Can't use == in where clause because of the possibility of nulls. That's why we're using object.Equals().
    if (maximoAssetNumber != "x") { predicate = predicate.And(scan => object.Equals(scan.MaximoAssetNumber, maximoAssetNumber)); }
    //if (manufacturerId != -1) { predicate = predicate.And(scan => object.Equals(scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId, manufacturerId)); }
    //if (partNumber != -1) { predicate = predicate.And(scan => object.Equals(scan.RawMaterialLabel.PartNumber, partNumber)); }

    return Db.LotEquipmentScanRecords.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList().Map();
}
```

I believe this is happening because manufacturerId and partNumber are **nullable** decimals. The issue is that those variables **can** be null, and we even want to filter the results by them being null. Does this just not work with EF, or is there an elegant way around this?

**EDIT**

To be clear, when manufacturerId is passed in as null, using this line returns five rows (which I can verify by looking at the DB):

```
if (manufacturerId != -1) { predicate = predicate.And(scan => object.Equals(scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId, manufacturerId)); }
```

Using this line, no rows are returned:

```
if (manufacturerId != -1) { predicate = predicate.And(scan => scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId); }
```

The problem is when I pass in a good manufacturerId, then I get the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit/Note from Bob Horn:** This answer was accepted because of the EDIT below, specifying a bug in EF. The first part of this answer didn't work.

By using `object.Equals(object, object)` as method of comparing two value types (Nullables are value types too), you are implicitly boxing them. Entity Framework does not support this.

Try using the `==` operator instead:

```
// Since scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId and manufacturerId are both Nullable<T> of the 
// same type the '==' operator should assert value equality, whether they have a value, or not.

// (int?)1 == (int?)1
// (int?)null == (int?)null
// (int?)1 != (int?)null

predicate = predicate.And(scan => scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId);
```

For value types the `==` operator asserts value equality, similarly to what the object.Equals() does for reference types.

**EDIT:**

Upon further investigation, there seems to be a [bug](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title#suggestion-1015361) in older versions of EF (pre EF5).

Hacky fix with your current version:

```
predicate = predicate.And(scan => 
   manufacturerId.HasValue
     ? scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId
     : scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId == null);
```

But if your application allows for it, upgrade to EF5.

Comment: What about the case where manufacturerId is null and I want to find rows where manufacturerId is null?

Comment: If the `ManufacturerId` property is equally nullable, you should be able to use the `==` operator.

Comment: I think that did it. I needed to use manufacturerId.Value, not just manufacturerId. Testing for accuracy now...

Comment: Oops, well actually, if you are comparing two Nullables,  then comparing with `Value` actually does *not* make sense. If however `scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId` is *not* nullable, then it does make sense. But then you cannot search for null rows, as the conceptual model does not allow for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, `scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId` is indeed nullable. We're dealing with third party data.

Comment: In that case, comparing `scan.RawMaterialLabel.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId` should definitely work. Which issue were you running into (ref. the //Note: )?

Comment: Rows weren't being returned unless I used `object.Equals()`. Using `==`, no rows were returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21544/discussion-between-yannick-motton-and-bob-horn)